# Create Custom excel output from NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, nopcommerce

I'am trying to export all selected products to an excel file, this works like it should work.
The problem is that I added a few product details for the product variants, which I would like to see in the exported excel file as well. My client needed the extra details so the product details will fit his products better.

**What I want to achieve:**

Add the custom added product detail fields to the excel export file as well. A picture of a few added product details below:
[image: Custom added product details]

I want to take the Custom added field values and add these to the exported excel file, in which class should I look for modifying the exported excel file?

**EDIT:**

I did more research and did find out that the excel file is filled and created in the ExportExcelSelected method on the ProductController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question, they can be added in the: `Exportmanager class` within the `ExportProductsToXlsx method`.